# $V=V_1\cap...\cap V_n$ neighbourhood of a point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> **Theorem**: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(Y,d_1),...,(Y,d_n)$metric spaces. Consider in $Y=(Y_1\times Y_n)$ one of the product metric $\delta_j(j=1,2,\infty)$.
>
> Let $(X,d)$ be another metric space. An application
>
> $f:(X,d)\to(Y,\delta_j),x\to(f_1(x),...,f_n(x))$
>
> is continuous in a point $a=(a_1,...,a_n)\in X$ if and only if each $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ a function $f_i:(X_i,d_i)\to Y,x\to f_i(x)$ is continuous in $a_i$.

**Proof**: As the product metrics $\delta_1,\delta_2$ and $\delta_\infty$ are equivalent, it suffices to show that the proposition holds in the metric $\delta_\infty$.

Let $B$ be a open of $(Y,\delta_{\infty})$. Suppose that each of the functions $f_i$ is is continuous in $a$. Let $V_i$ be an neighbourhood of $f_i(a)$ on $Y_i$. So $V=V_1\cap...\cap V_n$ is a neighbourhood of $f(a)$ in $X$. As $f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(V_1)\cap...\cap f^{-1}(V_n)$ and $f^{-1}_i(V_i)$ is the neighbourhood of $a$, therefore $f^{-1}(V)$ is in the neighbourhood of $a$. So, $f$ is continuous in $a$.

**Notes**: Metrics:$\delta_1=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}d_i(x_i,y_i),\:\:\:\delta_2=(\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}(d_i(x_i,y_i))^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\:\:\:,\delta_\infty=\max\{d_i(x_i,y_i):1\leqslant j\leqslant n\}$

**Questions**:

I am not understanding certain anspects of this proof:

**1)** Why does the author writes $V=V_1\cap...\cap V_n$ as the neighbourhood of $f(a)$? If we think on $\mathbb{R}^3$ the neighbourhood of each axis does not intersect with neigborhood on the other axis given a point on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Did not the author mean instead $V=V_1\cup...\cup V_n$?

**2)** The author writes "$f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(V_1)\cap...\cap f^{-1}(V_n)$". Did he not mean instead $f^{-1}(V)=f_1^{-1}(V_1)\cap...\cap f_n^{-1}(V_n)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the biggest confusion here comes from the fact that the author writes the $V_i$ as elements of the topology of $Y$ without saying how this is done. (I guess he writes about it earlier). But when constructing the product topology you take the projections $\pi_i: Y \to Y_i$ and look at the *inverse images* of open sets as a basis of the topology. Therefore $V_i$ in $Y$ is the preimage of the set $V_i \subset Y_i$ under $\pi_i$, so it is $(Y_1,\dots,V_i,\dots,Y_n)$. Thats why you take the intersection of all these neighbourhoods to get another one. 
This should (hopefully) answer both of your questions.